# Peewee ORM как можно посмотреть sql-код запроса

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, peewee

Подскажите как в Peewee можно посмотреть код запроса, например такого:`MyTable.select().where(column1 == 'value1').order_by(MyTable.name)`?

Comment: попробуй `.__sql__()` или `.sql`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Это метод какого класса и он вроде с обязательным аргументом вызывается?

Comment: первое метод, второе атрибут. у разных типов запросов есть такие  методы. в этом случае от селекта он тянется

Comment: там ещё контекст надо где-то взять... лучше в документации посмотреть)

Comment: да, получилось с помощью .sql() спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Базовый класс запросов `BaseQuery()` имеет метод `.sql()`, который вернет запрос и параметры. Пробуйте:

```
MyTable.select().where(column1 == 'value1').order_by(MyTable.name).sql()
```

Answer (score 1):

полезная функция `dir() dir(MyTable.select().where(column1 == 'value1').order_by(MyTable.name))`
покажет какие методы есть

Comment: спасибо посмотрю